# How did Google make these 3d buttons?

Tags: css, material-design

How did they make those 3d buttons with the shadows for their [doodle AI thing](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/)

They look like this:

[image: picture of the google button in question]

I snooped around in the CSS, but there's nothing special in the element's styles.

EDIT: If you're going to instantaneously downvote, could you tell me why, so I can try to fix the problem?

Comment: background image(sprite) https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/static/svg/buttons_large.svg, use firebug or developer's tool F12 to inspect

Comment: And if you wonder ... they use the `:active` state to toggle the position

Comment: I downvoted because it is pretty easy to discover how they did it by inspecting the element. In pretty much all browsers, you can right click on the element and click on something like "Inspect Element" ("Inspect" in Chrome). And in the right sidebar it will show you the CSS relevant to that exact element. You don't have to scan all the CSS rules to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a background image sprite:](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/static/svg/buttons_large.svg)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't snoop very hard...

```
.button.button-yellow, 
.button.button-green, 
.button.button-medium-gray
{
    background-image: url(/static/svg/buttons_large.svg);
}
```